# How to add Keras- Gaussian noise to image data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Importing the modules:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GaussianNoise
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

Re-scaling the data

```
X_train = X_train/255
X_test = X_test/255
plt.imshow(X_train[0])
```

Adding Gaussian Noise with std dev=0.2

```
sample = GaussianNoise(0.2)
noisey = sample(X_test[0:2],training=True)   #plt.imshow(noisey[0])
```

Getting Error:

`ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float64 for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("gaussian_noise_4_1/random_normal:0", shape=(2, 28, 28), dtype=float32)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this in my localhost for Jupyter Notebook and the following was the result with a warning.

[image: Attempt with warning]

From the warning it's clear that the problem of Type casting which is very costly.
You can improve it as:

```
X_train = X_train.astype('float32') / 255

X_test = X_test.astype('float32') / 255
```

Comment: You just copy/pasted my answer. Please refrain from plagiarism in the future.

Comment: @NicolasGervais I am sorry but I did not see your answer but right now. I had no intention of doing so. I just faced the similar problem about a week ago and learnt the exact reason and method from a colleague.

Answer (score 4):

Type casting is costly, and so Tensorflow doesn't do automatic type casting. As a default, Tensorflow's dtype is `float32`, and the dataset you imported has a dtype `float64`. You will just have to pass the optional dtype argument to `GaussianNoise`:

```
sample = GaussianNoise(0.2, dtype=tf.float64)
```

Or cast the array:

```
noisey = sample(X_test[0:2].astype(np.float32),training=True)
```

I suggest the second one.

Comment: Thanx. Incorporated your suggestion, but if I try to plot as `plt.imshow(noisey[0])` I end up getting the following error:

 `TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float`

Comment: oh you're right. i edited the answer so you can now plot it